# Dojo Composite/Group validation

Tags: validation, dojo

Given 2 text fields that (e.g. House Number, and House Name) on a form, and in order to be valid the user must enter a number or name in the appropriate field before the 'group' of 2 fields is considered valid.

A user could enter just a house number, or a house name, but entering a value in either field marks both of them valid.

Is there a way to do this in Dijit/Dojo? The idea of a composite or group of validation elements would be perfect.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[dijit.form.Form](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/Form) has an `isValid` function that by default makes sure all of its children dijit.form widgets are valid.  You can use stock [dijit.form.ValidationTextBox](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox) widgets in combination with attributes like regexp and required, or descendants like NumberTextBox to specify validation rules.